# Exception while using custom releaseTagName with pushChanges in sbt-release

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-release

I'm setting a custom tag name as part of release process using sbt-release

```
releaseTagName := s"v${version.value}-${name.value}",
```

Problem is, during the pushChanges release step where [tags are pushed](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-release/blob/master/src/main/scala/Vcs.scala#L166) to github, it seems to use two tags.

```
  [info]  * [new tag]         list -> list
  [info]  * [new tag]         v0.3-primary -> v0.3-primary
  [info]  ! [rejected]        v0.1 -> v0.1 (already exists)
```

v0.3-primary is the one I configured with `releaseTagName`. Tag v0.1 already exists and hence this step fails. I can't seem to figure why its pushing this tag.

```
  [info] Setting version to '0.4-SNAPSHOT'.
  [info] Reapplying settings...
  [info] Set current project to primary (in build file:/source/capture-app/)
  [info] [master b594aeb] Setting version to 0.4-SNAPSHOT
  [info]  1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
  Push changes to the remote repository (y/n)? [y]
  [info]    4f29ecf..b594aeb  master -> master
  [info] To https://github.com/...
  [info]  * [new tag]         list -> list
  [info]  * [new tag]         v0.3-primary -> v0.3-primary
  [info]  ! [rejected]        v0.1 -> v0.1 (already exists)
  [info] error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/...
  [info] hint: Updates were rejected because the tag already exists in the remote.
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit value: 1
          at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
          at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.slurp(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:131)
          at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.$bang$bang(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:102)
          at sbtrelease.ReleaseStateTransformations$$anonfun$pushChangesAction$1.apply(ReleaseExtra.scala:258)
          at sbtrelease.ReleaseStateTransformations$$anonfun$pushChangesAction$1.apply(ReleaseExtra.scala:245)
```

Anyone has an explanation on what's going on?

Comment: Is the v0.1 tag always created, or is it just an unpushed tag from some previous run? The release plugin tries to push tags, if the problematic tag was already in working copy, I suppose it would fail the same way - without actually causing the problem.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? Like I said, tag v0.1 already exists and it was also pushed successfully earlier. Since then I moved to a new tag naming convention with "v0.3-primary". Now if I release version 0.4, a tag named "v0.4-primary" gets pushed. Along with that why does it push(and fail) tag v0.1 that already exists??

Comment: It would not push an existing tag, unless it differs. Try to remove it from the working copy and fetch it from the remote again, with `git tag -d v0.1` and `git fetch origin tag v0.1`

Comment: ah, I get it now. What is the command to see if any changes were made? Similar to git status of diff but on a tag?

Comment: Can you add this as an answer?